# Best way to set file-download permissions on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, file, download

I want to secure some files that are on my site, but also I want to give permissions to some users to download that files. What is the best way to do it?

I have only one idea - generate temporary random URL's like `/files/hdad8fda299asnfqe/foo.bar`

But I hardly want that other users can not use others URLs.

Do you know any gem that can help me or suggest another way to secure files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to secure downloads for real is to move them outside of the 'public' path and feed them to the user through a controller that checks authorization. The most efficient way to do this (that I know of) is to use xsendfile.

So for example first you make a new directory in your app, let's say "downloads" (you can name it whatever of course, and you can put it anywhere in your system that your Rails server can access.)

```
mkdir downloads
```

Now make a nice new route for the downloads:

```
match '/downloads/*filename' => 'downloads#download'
```

Then create a new controller (or just an action in an existing controller)

```
class DownloadsController
  def download
    filename = [params[:filename], params[:format]].join('.')
    path = Rails.root.join( 'downloads', filename )

    if File.exists?(path) && user.can_download?( filename )
      send_file( path, x_sendfile: true )
    else
      raise ActionController::RoutingError, "resource not found"
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can navigate to

```
/downloads/path/my_file.txt
```

And let User#can_download? handle the permission checking..

It's a little different if the files belong to an object rather than being loose files in the filesystem, you'd have to ask for ids rather than filenames and determine the path from the associated model, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Peter has the right idea. It's unclear if you want a granular level of authorization per file or if it's just certain users that can download ANY file. If the latter, you're better off with a before_filter that restricts access to the download action.

Comment: downloads/../../../etc/passwd with the right path will exist, right? What is someone wants to just download a random file without checking the user?